# How to merge two array and group by key?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to merge two array and group by key?

Example:

```
my_list = [3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 8]

keys = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7]
```

Expected outcome:

```
[[1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 6], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: can you explain the logic?

Comment: If you want to operate on key-value pairs, you should use dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it right, the list of keys map to the list of values. You can use the `zip` function to iterate through two lists at the same time. Its convenient in this case. Also check up on the beautiful `defaultdict` functionality - we can use it to fill a list without initialising it explicitely.

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)  # a dictionary which by default returns a list
for key, val in zip(keys, my_list):
    result[key].append(val)

result
# {1: [3, 4], 2: [5, 6], 3: [4], 5: [6], 7: [8]}
```

You can then go to a list (but not sure why you would want to) with:

```
final = []
for key, val in result.items():
    final.append([key] + val)  # add key back to the list of values

final
# [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 6], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: Because i have to prepare data for elastic-search. I do the way that like your code. And i was not sure of the performance so i have to found some ways to compare all of them and choose the best way. Thanks for all things

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to write it by your own using `set()` to remove duplicates, so I have made a function called `merge_group`

```
my_list = [3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 8]
keys = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7]

def merge_group(input_list : list, input_key : list):
    result = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(my_list):
        result.append([my_list[i], keys[i]])
        i += 1
    j = 0
    while j < len(result):
        if j+1 < len(result):    
            check_sum = result[j] + result[j+1]
            check_sum_set = list(set(check_sum))
            if len(check_sum) != len(check_sum_set):
                result[j] = check_sum_set        
        j += 1
    return result        


print(merge_group(my_list, keys))
```